# How to capture data within my controller from form a builder class working with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have built a form using a builder and by a creating a class as below

```
// form builder class testform

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class testForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add(
            'startDate',
            DateType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'startDate',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
```

I am able to collect the data of this form in my controller and query my database using the below which works

```
// controller where I get data after submitting

 $form = $this->createForm(testForm::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $start = date_format($form->get('startDate')->getData(), 'Y-m-d');

        }
```

The issue i face now is requirements for receiving this data in my controller has changed.
I am required to get the data from the form class builder without using the `getData()` method, I am required to capture the data using the below object

```
   $form = $this->createForm(testForm::class);
  $form->handleRequest($request);
```

Please how do I do this effectively, as I have only known how to use the get method in all my practice

This is what I am trying at the moment

```
$form = $this->createForm(testForm::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        foreach ($form as $filled) {
            echo $filled['startDate'];
        } 
    }
```

here I am trying to get the value of startDate from my for each loop

but I get this error `Child "startDate" does not exist.`

But when I `dump($filled);`

I get this below which shows startDate is present

[screen shot as for dump output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok7pi.png)

So question is how do I get the data without using the `getData()` method?

is my approach wrong

Comment: Question is __why__ do you need underlying data?

Comment: You should use a class object model with the desired setter/getter methods. The object would be passed by-reference to the Symfony form. See: [Creating Form Classes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes). In the example you can then just use `$task->getStartDate()` to retrieve the submitted data.

Comment: the data is needed to query my database I am passing that to my repository, I will update my question with that

Comment: alright @WillB. I will read and try this out

Comment: Otherwise you would change `foreach ($form as $filled) {` to `foreach ($form->getData() as $filled) {` which should produce an array of the fields. But an object model is still strongly encouraged as it provides a structure to the data that can be referenced and debugged as opposed to an array which is abstract.